# Poincare-Bendixson Theorem to prove existence of a nontrivial periodic solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem to prove the existence of a nontrivial periodic solution of the following DE: $z'' + (z^2 + (z')^4 - 2)z = 0$